# Send data from Broadcast Receiver to simple java class while app is closed

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I'm building an android app to handle SMS, I made Broadcast Receiver to listen for incoming SMS. when it comes it should send SMS content to another class to do so some logic, I used interface to achieve that, this is my code.

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static void initSmsFetcher(SmsFetcher mSmsFetcher){
        smsFetcher = mSmsFetcher;
    }
    @SuppressLint("UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver")
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null){
            Object[] smsextras = (Object[]) extras.get( "pdus" );

            for (Object smsextra : smsextras) {
                SmsMessage smsmsg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) smsextra);

                smsFetcher.onSmsReceived(smsmsg);
                

            }

        }
    }


   

}
 interface SmsFetcher{
    void onSmsReceived(SmsMessage smsMessage);
 }
```

this is my simple class.

```
public class SmsEasy implements SmsFetcher{
    SmsEasy(){
        SmsReceiver.initSmsFetcher(this);

    }

@Override
    public void onSmsReceived(SmsMessage smsMessage) {
        // Do some logic.
    }

}
```

And this is my MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SmsEasy smsEasy;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        smsEasy = new SmsEasy();

    }


}
```

I registered my Broadcast Receiver in Manifest.
This is working fine when my app is running, but the problem appears when the app is closed, it tells me that **smsFetcher** is null in this line:
**smsFetcher.onSmsReceived(smsmsg);** but my receiver still capturing sms fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your process does not live forever. At the time the SMS arrives, Android may need to create a process for app code. When it does that, it will create an instance of `SmsReceiver` and call `onReceive()` on it. It will not create an instance of `MainActivity`.

As a result, `SmsReceiver` needs to work *completely independently* from `MainActivity`. Do not assume that `MainActivity` has done anything in your app's process at the point when `onReceive()` of `SmsReceiver` has been called.

Comment: so it means the implementation of interface is wrong in my case and i should move "some logic" inside the receiver, right?

Comment: @AhmedLaggoun: That is a good starting point. Eventually, you might look into dependency inversion frameworks (such as Dagger/Hilt). You could then inject your SMS processing logic into the receiver at runtime.